# How to resolve this in BeanShell?

Tags: testing, jmeter, jar, jmx, beanshell

I am using this script to update values in JSON file

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

try {

    String filePath = "blob";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    String jsonContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");


    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonContent);

    String extractedValue1 = vars.get("CASE_TYPE_ID");
    jsonObject.get("caseType").put("id",extractedValue1);
    String extractedValue2 = vars.get("CASE_CONFIG_ID");
    jsonObject.put("caseConfigId", extractedValue2)

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, jsonObject.toJSONString(), "UTF-8");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error updating JSON file: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

When I run the script I got this error:

> In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser; imp . . . '' Encountered "FileUtils" at line 20, column 5.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code, line 18 must end with a semicolon.

---

Apart from this:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to Groovy. More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)
2. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) so you don't need to use 3rd-party libraries. Example code you can use instead:

   ```
   def original = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('blob'))
   original.caseType = vars.get('CASE_TYPE_ID')
   original.caseConfigId = vars.get('CASE_CONFIG_ID')

   new File('blob').withWriter { writer ->
       writer << new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(original).toPrettyString()
   }
   ```
3. If you run your test with > 1 user they will be concurrently writing into the same file ([race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)) which will result in data corruption or loss. Consider using different file names or if you cannot - use different folders, one per user.